# J2ME:HttpConnection not close immideatly in Nokia SDK

Tags: java-me, nokia, httpconnection

I trying to make HttpConnection with RequestProperty "Connection", "close"

and request wait long time on conn.getResponseCode(); .
And i try to close connection in another thread.

But Connection not close immideatly it take 2 to 3 min to close the connection. Any solution on this problem Please help..

Connection Close immediate in CLDC Oracle Java(TM) Platform Micro Edition SDK 3.0.5

But it take Time in Nokia SDK 2.0

Thanks